# Solving a system of PDEs on a piecewise polynomial domain

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, finite-element-method

I wish to solve following system of equations with Dirchlet and Neumann boundary conditions on an piecewise polynomial (cubic spline) shaped domain as showed here.
[image]

```
Emod = 2*10^6; \[Nu] = 0.3; \[Rho] = 7860; g = 10; F = 100000; Gmod = 769231;
System = {Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 
     2 \[Nu])) ((1 - \[Nu]) (D[r*U[r, z], r, r])/r - \[Nu]*
   D[r* V[r, z], r, z]/r) +(Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[U[r, z], z, z] + D[V[r, z], r, z]),(Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[r* U[r, z], r, z]/ r + 
D[r* V[r, z], r, r]/r) + (Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 2 \[Nu]))) ((1 - \[Nu]) D[V[r, z], z, z] - \[Nu]*D[U[r, z], r, z])};
{uif, vif} = NDSolveValue[{System == {0, NeumannValue[F, z == 4]}, DirichletCondition[{U[r, z] == 0., V[r, z] == 0.}, z == 0]}, {U, V}, {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 4}];
```

I know how to solve and plot it in a rectangular domain: {r, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 4}.
I'd also like to solve this on the region, where {z, 0, 4} and r(z) is defined as a cubic spline function: $r_{i}=a_{i}+b_{i}(z-z_{i})+c_{i}(z-z_{i})^2+d_{i}(z-z_{i})^3$ for an arbitrary number of intervals.

This cubic spline is interpolation of an exponential function: 
$r(z)=r_0 e^\frac{\rho r_0^2 gz\pi}{2F}$, where $r_0=0.5$. The function coefficients $(a_{i},..d_{i})$ depend on the number of intervals.
The coefficients are (for 10 intervals):

a={0.5, 0.571811, 0.653935, 0.747854, 0.855263, 0.978097, 1.11857, 
1.27922, 1.46295};

b={0.15105, 0.172638, 0.197461, 0.225813, 0.258247, 0.295335, 0.337756, 
0.386248, 0.441788};

c={0.0224672, 0.0261063, 0.0297453, 0.0340466, 0.0389299, 0.0445182, 
0.0509301, 0.0581749, 0.0667915};

d={0.00272929, 0.00272929, 0.00322598, 0.00366244, 0.0041912, 
0.00480898, 0.00543356, 0.0064625, 0.0064625}.

[image]

Comment: You did not define $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i,z_i$.

Comment: They depend on number of intervals, and are obtained by interpolation of exponential function., r(z). Should I also write that?

Comment: Yes, add the equation `r=r[z]`

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning, we solve equations in the domain of a bounded curve `r=r0*Exp[k*z]`

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
r0 = .5; Emod = 

2*10^6; \[Nu] = 0.3; \[Rho] = 7860; g = 10; u = 0.1; Gmod = 769231; \
g = 10; F = 100000; k = \[Rho]*g*.5^2*Pi/2/F;
reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= r0*Exp[k*z] && 0 <= z <= 4, {r, z}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg];
mesh["Wireframe"]

System = {Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 
          2 \[Nu])) ((1 - \[Nu]) (D[r*U[r, z], r, r])/r - \[Nu]*
        D[r*V[r, z], r, z]/r) + (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[U[r, z], z, 
        z] + D[V[r, z], r, 
        z]), (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[r*U[r, z], r, z]/r + 
       D[r*V[r, z], r, r]/
        r) + (Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 2 \[Nu]))) ((1 - \[Nu]) D[
         V[r, z], z, z] - \[Nu]*D[U[r, z], r, z])};
{uif, vif} = 
  NDSolveValue[{System == {0, 
      NeumannValue[10000., r > 0]}, 
    DirichletCondition[{U[r, z] == 0., V[r, z] == 0.}, z == 4]}, {U, 
    V}, {r, z} \[Element] mesh];
mesh = uif["ElementMesh"];
    {Show[{
   mesh["Wireframe"[ "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]],
   ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, {uif, vif}][
    "Wireframe"[
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}], 
 ContourPlot[uif[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "u", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[vif[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] mesh, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "v", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: fig1]

Now we take `nint` points on the curve and construct an interpolation by third order polynomials

```
    nint = 20; point = Table[{z, r0*Exp[k*z]}, {z, 0, 4, 4/nint}]; f = 
 Interpolation[point];
```

Build a new mesh and solve the problem.

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= f[z] && 0 <= z <= 4, {r, z}];
mesh1 = ToElementMesh[reg1];
mesh1["Wireframe"]
{uif1, vif1} = 
  NDSolveValue[{System == {0, NeumannValue[10000., r > 0]}, 
    DirichletCondition[{U[r, z] == 0., V[r, z] == 0.}, z == 4]}, {U, 
    V}, {r, z} \[Element] mesh1];

mesh1 = uif1["ElementMesh"];
{Show[{
   mesh1["Wireframe"[ "MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]],
   ElementMeshDeformation[mesh1, {uif1, vif1}][
    "Wireframe"[
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}], 
 ContourPlot[uif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] mesh1, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "u", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[vif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] mesh1, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "v", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Fugure 2]

Then we can determine the difference of the two solutions when `r = 0` as

```
{Row[{"nint = ", nint}], 
 Plot[{uif[0, z] - uif1[0, z]}, {z, 0, 4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "\[Delta]u"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 Plot[{vif[0, z] - vif1[0, z]}, {z, 0, 4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"z", "\[Delta]v"}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

If coefficients `a, b, c, d` are given, then the solution to the problem is as follows

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
a = {0.5, 0.571811, 0.653935, 0.747854, 0.855263, 0.978097, 1.11857, 
   1.27922, 1.46295};
b = {0.15105, 0.172638, 0.197461, 0.225813, 0.258247, 0.295335, 
   0.337756, 0.386248, 0.441788};
c = {0.0224672, 0.0261063, 0.0297453, 0.0340466, 0.0389299, 0.0445182,
    0.0509301, 0.0581749, 0.0667915};
d = {0.00272929, 0.00272929, 0.00322598, 0.00366244, 0.0041912, 
   0.00480898, 0.00543356, 0.0064625, 0.0064625};
zz = Range[0, 4, 4/9];
f[z_] = Piecewise[
   Table[{a[[i]] + b[[i]] (z - zz[[i]]) + c[[i]] (z - zz[[i]])^2 + 
      d[[i]] (z - zz[[i]])^3, zz[[i]] <= z < zz[[i + 1]]}, {i, 
     Length[a]}]];

reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= f[z] && 0 <= z <= 4, {r, z}];
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[reg, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> .001]

r0 = .5; Emod = 
 2*10^6; \[Nu] = 0.3; \[Rho] = 7860; g = 10; u = 0.1; Gmod = 769231; \
g = 10; F = 100000; k = \[Rho]*g*.5^2*
  Pi/2/F; System = {Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 
         2 \[Nu])) ((1 - \[Nu]) (D[r*U[r, z], r, r])/r - \[Nu]*
       D[r*V[r, z], r, z]/r) + (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[U[r, z], z, 
       z] + D[V[r, z], r, 
       z]), (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[r*U[r, z], r, z]/r + 
      D[r*V[r, z], r, r]/
       r) + (Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 2 \[Nu]))) ((1 - \[Nu]) D[V[r, z],
         z, z] - \[Nu]*D[U[r, z], r, z])};
{uif1, vif1} = 
 NDSolveValue[{System == {0, NeumannValue[10000., r > 0]}, 
   DirichletCondition[{U[r, z] == 0., V[r, z] == 0.}, z == 4]}, {U, 
   V}, {r, z} \[Element] mesh]



meshu = uif1["ElementMesh"];
{Show[{meshu["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]], 
   ElementMeshDeformation[meshu, {uif1, vif1}][
    "Wireframe"[
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}], 
 ContourPlot[uif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] meshu, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "u", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[vif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] meshu, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "v", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 4]

Code for version 10.3

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
a = {0.5, 0.571811, 0.653935, 0.747854, 0.855263, 0.978097, 1.11857, 
   1.27922, 1.46295};
b = {0.15105, 0.172638, 0.197461, 0.225813, 0.258247, 0.295335, 
   0.337756, 0.386248, 0.441788};
c = {0.0224672, 0.0261063, 0.0297453, 0.0340466, 0.0389299, 0.0445182,
    0.0509301, 0.0581749, 0.0667915};
d = {0.00272929, 0.00272929, 0.00322598, 0.00366244, 0.0041912, 
   0.00480898, 0.00543356, 0.0064625, 0.0064625};
zz = Range[0, 4, 4/9];
f[z_] := Piecewise[
   Table[{a[[i]] + b[[i]] (z - zz[[i]]) + c[[i]] (z - zz[[i]])^2 + 
      d[[i]] (z - zz[[i]])^3, zz[[i]] <= z <= zz[[i + 1]]}, {i, 
     Length[a]}]];

reg = ImplicitRegion[0 <= r <= f[z] && 0 <= z <= 4, {r, z}];
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[reg, {{0, f[4]}, {0, 4}}, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> .001, Frame -> True, Method -> "Continuation"]
r0 = .5; Emod = 
 2*10^6; \[Nu] = 0.3; \[Rho] = 7860; g = 10; u = 0.1; Gmod = 769231; \
g = 10; F = 100000; k = \[Rho]*g*.5^2*
  Pi/2/F; System = {Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 
         2 \[Nu])) ((1 - \[Nu]) (D[r*U[r, z], r, r])/r - \[Nu]*
       D[r*V[r, z], r, z]/r) + (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[U[r, z], z, 
       z] + D[V[r, z], r, 
       z]), (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[r*U[r, z], r, z]/r + 
      D[r*V[r, z], r, r]/
       r) + (Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 2 \[Nu]))) ((1 - \[Nu]) D[V[r, z],
         z, z] - \[Nu]*D[U[r, z], r, z])};
{uif1, vif1} = 
 NDSolveValue[{System == {0, NeumannValue[10000., r > 0]}, 
   DirichletCondition[{U[r, z] == 0., V[r, z] == 0.}, z == 4]}, {U, 
   V}, {r, z} \[Element] mesh]



meshu = uif1["ElementMesh"];
{Show[{meshu["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "BoundaryElements"]], 
   ElementMeshDeformation[meshu, {uif1, vif1}][
    "Wireframe"[
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[]]]]}], 
 ContourPlot[uif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] meshu, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "u", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic], 
 ContourPlot[vif1[r, z], {r, z} \[Element] meshu, PlotRange -> All, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> Hue, 
  FrameLabel -> {"r", "z"}, PlotLabel -> "v", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Comment: This looks good, i just find one mistake in your code, mesh1 = ToElementMesh[reg1]; instead of [reg}, then i get different results than with the exponential curve, but i think that this is normal because the discrete points are different. Mathematica then shows the error: InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {4.00028} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

Comment: @LejlaS You're right, there is a difference between the two solutions. I corrected the code and added Figure 3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we know its third order polynomial interpolation? I don't see it in your code. its normaly with [InterpolationOrder -> 3]

Comment: @LejlaS This is an automatic option `InterpolationOrder -> 3` for `Interpolation[]`.

Comment: How to get values of displacements at specific nodes?

Comment: @LejlaS Find the coordinates of the nodes `coord = mesh["Coordinates"]`, take a specific node `coord[[45]]` (it gives` {1.51781, 3.59752}`), determine  values of displacements at specific node `{uif[r, z], vif[r, z]} /. {r -> coord[[45, 1]], z -> coord[[45, 2]]}`, we get `{-0.00266332, -0.00259711}`.

Comment: Very helpful!!!

Comment: How to get an output in a form of a table? I would like to extract, uif[r], i tried with: data = Table[{r, Evaluate[{uif[r,0]} /. sol]}, {r, 0, 1, 0.5}]; where sol={uif,vif}

Comment: @LejlaS Use `Table[{r, uif[r, 0]}, {r, 0, .5, .01}]`

Comment: It doesnt work:i am getting this:{0., uif[0., 0]}, {0.01, uif[0.01, 0]}, {0.02, uif[0.02, 0}...

Comment: @LejlaS if you use the second code, then there `Table[{r, uif1[r, 0]}, {r, 0, .5, .01}]`

Comment: How to define implicit domain when i have a set of data for the coefficients, a,b,c,d. I want to make a region to be not an third order polynomial interpolation but r(z) to be defined as a cubic spline function out of those coefficients., like i wrote at the top of my post.

Comment: @LejlaS Then we return to my first question. You did not define $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i$ :)

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot about that. I have uploaded the coefficients now.

Comment: @LejlaS OK! See update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you once more! I have copy-passed your code but i only get the interpolation on the domain :r= {0., 0.676247} ,z= {0., 1.}, what happens with the rest of domain? i also get the error: No places were found on the boundary where z==4. was True, so DirichletCondition[U==0,z==4.] will effectively be ignored. See the image I add above.

Comment: @LejlaS Very interesting. What is your version?

Comment: My version of Mathematica is :11.1

Comment: @LejlaS  I checked the code for version 10.3. It really does not work. And on version 12 it works. I will try to configure under the old version.

Comment: @LejlaS I added code for version 10.3

Comment: Oh wow, thank you, very appreciated...

Comment: @LejlaS you're welcome!

Comment: I am not particularly happy with the mesh. I would like to use quadrilateral elements instead of triangular. I tried with mesh1 = ToQuadMesh[mesh]; but i don't get uniform element distribution. How to make it structurized ?I uploaded my try..