# Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[None]

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, mesh

This is a follow-up question to an earlier question:[Solving a system of PDEs on a piecewise polynomial domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/199022/solving-a-system-of-pdes-on-a-piecewise-polynomial-domain/199036?noredirect=1#comment523200_199036).

I tried to solve the system of equations from one of my previous post with the different coefficients:

```
<<NDSolve`FEM`
a={0.3340527327277163,0.3371936591328173,0.3414675219853483,0.3497392153889085,0.3639038048503026,0.3860859499869367,0.4188891103386034,0.4661393563881397,0.5362863587633145};
b={0.005838094929284841`,0.007086837497897063`,0.01217741412156561`,0.02129794898356325`,0.03477401117328845`,0.05322933294625294`,0.0780520229353152`,0.1131897349856148`,0.176837371960602`};
c={0.002743004112710833`,0.002809670779377499`,0.01145379740325422`,0.0205212034394947`,0.0303211,0.0415245,0.05585105247539011`,0.07905985211317404`,0.1432071831937214`};
d={0.0000499999999999997`,0.006483094967907541`,0.006800554527180358`,0.007349952365540251`,0.008402500546716287`,0.01074493386466502`,0.01740659972833794`,0.04811049831041051`,0.3922591252051698`};
zz=Range[0,4,4/9];
f[z_]=Piecewise[Table[{a[[i]]+b[[i]] (z-zz[[i]])+c[[i]] (z-zz[[i]])^2+d[[i]] (z-zz[[i]])^3,zz[[i]]<=z<=zz[[i+1]]},{i,Length[a]}]];
 r0=.33; 

 mesh=ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{0,0},{r0,4}],"MaxBoundaryCellMeasure"->.125];
F={r,z}\[Function]{r f[z],z};
mesh1=ToElementMesh["Coordinates"->F@@@mesh["Coordinates"],"MeshElements"->mesh["MeshElements"]];
mesh1["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
Emod=2*10^11;\[Nu]=0.3;\[Rho]=7850;g=9.8066;
System = {Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 
       2 \[Nu])) ((1 - \[Nu]) (D[r*U[r, z], r, r])/r - \[Nu]*
     D[r*V[r, z], r, z]/r) + (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[U[r, z], z,
      z] + D[V[r, z], r, z]) == 
0, (Emod/(2 (1 + \[Nu]))) (D[r*U[r, z], r, z]/r + 
    D[r*V[r, z], r, r]/
     r) + (Emod/((1 + \[Nu]) (1 - 2 \[Nu]))) ((1 - \[Nu]) D[
      V[r, z], z, z] - \[Nu]*D[U[r, z], r, z]) == 0, U[r, 4] == 0,
V[r, 4] == 0, V[r, 0] == 0.00001}

{uif1,vif1}=NDSolveValue[System,{U,V},Element[{r,z},mesh1]];
\[Sigma]r  = Function[{r,z},Evaluate[Emod/((\[Nu]+1) (2 \[Nu]-1)) ((\[Nu]-1) D[uif1[r,z],r]-\[Nu] (D[vif1[r,z],r]+(uif1[r,z])/r))]];
P = Plot3D[\[Sigma]r[r, z], Element[{r, z}, mesh1], PlotRange -> All]
Export["Sigma_r.dat",First@FirstCase[P,_GraphicsComplex,None,\[Infinity]],"TSV"];
```

I dont have anymore problem at this place with the error : Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[None]. But not i get error: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered". I was not having this problem before. 
Also when i try to calculate the equivalent stress:

```
\[Sigma]eq = Function {r, z} Evaluate[
Sqrt[(Emod/((\[Nu] + 1) (2 \[Nu] - 1)) ((\[Nu] - 1) D[uif1[r, z], 
         r] - \[Nu] (D[vif1[r, z], r] + (uif1[r, z])/
           r)))^2 + (Emod/((\[Nu] + 1) (2 \[Nu] - 1)) ((\[Nu] - 
          1) D[vif1[r, z], 
         r] - \[Nu] (D[uif1[r, z], r])))^2 + (Emod/((\[Nu] + 
          1) (2 \[Nu] - 1)) ((\[Nu] - 1) (uif1[r, z])/
         r - \[Nu] (D[uif1[r, z], r] + D[vif1[r, z], r])))^2  ]]];
EQsigma =Plot3D[[Sigma]eq[r, z], Element[{r, z}, mesh1], PlotRange -> All] Export["Eqsigma.dat", First@FirstCase[EQsigma, _GraphicsComplex, None, [Infinity]], "TSV"];
```

I get an error:Indeterminate expression 3.37817*10^17+ComplexInfinity+ComplexInfinity encountered and : Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in First[None].

Comment: When you copy and paste your code there are some non code pieces left ("enter code here"). It would be good to remove that.

Comment: @user21 last week I managed to get a set of numerical answers, but this week Mathematica reports "Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered."  I don't think there is any infinity point in the function. Mathematica can behave strange  sometimes. Why is this happening.

Comment: Something must have changed. Hard to say without that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the `Plot3D` you generated is empty. Which may be just the result for this solution. Also not that for `r=0` you are dividing by 0 in your `sigmar` function. Otherwise you could use this:

```
Plot3D[\[Sigma]r[r, z], Element[{r, z}, mesh1], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: it works now with your code.. thanks again

Comment: @LejlaS, you are welcome.